# Hibernate 5.0.12 Wrong column definition escape with Mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Hibernate + Spring JPA and Mysql 5.7 as DBMS. I want to use some reserved keywords as column name and for that I eanbled:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

Some columns have a custom definition like:

```
@CreatedDate
    @Column(updatable = false, columnDefinition = "DATETIME(6)")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
```

Unfortunately Hibernate translate this as:

```
`created_date` `DATETIME(6)`
```

instead of

```
`created_date` DATETIME(6)
```

I opened an issue on Hibernate JIRA [(JIRA)](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11789); I was wondering if there is a workaround to use meanwhile.

Comment: 1. Enclose the keyword with square brackets [].

@Column(name = "[DESC]", nullable = false)
public String getDesc() {
 return this.desc;
}

2. Use double quotes (“) to enclose it.

@Column(name = "\"DESC\"", nullable = false)
public String getDesc() {
 return this.desc;
}

Comment: I used spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true because I want Hibernate always eclose that, also in queries. I don't want do that manually in queries.

Answer (score 6):

I found the right solution thanks to Hibernate people:

To avoid that column definition is quoted there is a specific setting:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers_skip_column_definitions=true
```

Unfortunately, right now, it works backwards ([see this bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11739)): so if you want to skip column definition you have to set it to **false**.

Comment: Does not works for me, set the property in application.properties from src/main/resources using spring boot but canot strip the quotes.

Comment: That bug is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

i found  a solution  for u just     @Column(name = ""to"") what ever u want repplace instead of to

Comment: This solution works,  Escaping quote is missing in the answer -  @Column(name = "\"to\"")

Answer (score 0):

Update JPA to lastest version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.2.11.Final